# Wireless Connection Repeatedly disconnects, strong signal

Tags: wireless, 14.04, dell, broadcom

The wireless connection on my Dell Inspiron 9100 repeatedly disconnects, especially when I try to access a weblink.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7894056/

Answer (score 0):

If StarJammers is a router over which you have administrative control, I suggest you check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I suggest we try a couple of driver parameters; from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options b43 nohwcrypt=1 qos=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
modprobe -r ssb
modprobe b43
exit
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.